# .htaccess remove all .php and id as default parameter after slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` file which helps me to rewrite the `http://domain/path/project.php?id=1` as `http://domain/path/project/1`.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ project.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ project.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ project.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

But I need all the php's in the current directory to be replaced in the same way. I have `edit_project.php?id=1`, `delete_project.php?id=1` etc. `id` is a default parameter for all the php's except some. So I want the htaccess to do the following.

`http://domain/path/*.php?id=1` as `http://domain/path/*/id`
and when there is no id, it should just look like `http://domain/path/*` and when there are other parameters, it should look like `http://domain/path/*?param=value`

Since I am new to .htaccess, any help would be appreciated. Also please explain me how this works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^path/([^/]+)/?([0-9]*)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

This will rewrite **/path/file/id** to **/file.php?id=id**

Since $1 represents match of first group of `([^/]+)` and $2 represents match of second group of `([0-9]*)`

Comment: Thanks, I will check and get back. Gimme some time :)

Comment: My current url is` /path/file.php?id=id` but I want it to be represented as `/path/file/id`

Comment: @Sibidharan I think you just need to fix one thing in your configuration above to make it work as expected

    `RewriteRule ^path/([^/]+)/?([0-9]*)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]`

so this part

     ?id=$2

Comment: @AhmedRashad I will try. Thanks.

Comment: @starkeen, I edited your answer to make it works as expected

Comment: @AhmedRashad Not working.. The `/file.php?id=id` stays intact!

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect /path/file.php?id=123 to /path/file/123
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(path/.+)\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# hide .php extension 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

# rewrite /path/file/123 to /path/file.php?id=123
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(path/[^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

# hide .php extension 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(path/[^/]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Make sure there is no .htaccess in `/path/` directory.

Comment: It looks like changing URLs, but throws `not found` error.